# Magento 2 Override Magento Checkout Model Cart updateItems function

Tags: magento2

I Need to Override updateItems function from \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
Also need to pass my custom helper class in __construct arguments . This is my __construct function of override class

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
Class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
{
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
                            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
                            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                            \Magento\Checkout\Model\ResourceModel\Cart $resourceCart, Session $checkoutSession, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager, \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry, \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState, \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository, ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
                            \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper, array $data = []
                            )
{
    $this->helper = $helper;
    parent::__construct($eventManager, $scopeConfig, $storeManager, $resourceCart, $checkoutSession, $customerSession, $messageManager, $stockRegistry, $stockState, $quoteRepository, $productRepository, $data);

}
}
```

After this i run setup:upgrade,compile, static content deploy commands. Also remove all folders in var. But when i pass the argument in __construct function. It is not working. It displays blank page. When i remove my arguments from __construct function. then page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override `updateItems` from checkout cart model class then you must add `preference` in your module `di.xml` file, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart" type="[Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Model\Cart" />
</config>
```

then, your custom module `app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Model/Cart.php` should look like this:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as MagentoCart;
use [Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Helper\Data;

class Cart extends MagentoCart
{
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(Data $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    // Code ...
}
```

then compile dependencies and that's all. Read this article to know more about [Overriding classes in Magento 2](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am doing exactly like this. But blank white page is showing.

Comment: Enable display_errors from app/bootstrap.php file and check what’s the exact error

Comment: Hi @adeel I have enabled the display_errors. This is error showing

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1368064 bytes) in /var/www/html/projectname/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php on line 75

Comment: Perfect, now just increase the memory_limit in php.ini file then it should work and also restart the server, but in case if it doesn’t work then try to run this command php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade and for Compilation command:
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: For Deployment, run this command:
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
You can also change 5G to max if the issue is not fixed. Btw, I would prefer to use commands instead of changing directly into php.ini